# How to make a material-ui TableRowColumn span multiple columns

Tags: html, material-ui

It's like the `html` `colspan` attribute. Some rows with different numbers of column than the others.

thanks

Answer (score 48):

Simply add the attribute, like:

```
<TableRowColumn colSpan={6}>
```

Comment: Material UI react complains there is no element named TableRowColumn.

Comment: TableRowColumn was removed from Material-UI at some point.  This was relevant for Material-UI early versions 0.x.  I don't see it in the 1.x branch at this point, let alone current versions.  So this answer is now out of date. Sorry.

Answer (score 42):

Just use the attribute "colSpan" to the `<TableCell>` element.

Example:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <Table className={classes.table}>
      <TableBody>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>Data 1</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Data 2</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell colSpan={2}>Data Two Columns</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  );
}
```

Comment: This works because as it says at https://material-ui.com/api/table-cell/ : "Any other props supplied will be provided to the root element (native element)."